# Не работает код. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.6

Даже погуглив я не смог найти решение проблемы. Данный код является калькулятором. Но почему-то работает только сложение... Вот ошибка: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Код:

```
inp = list(input())

i = 0

while i != len(inp):

    if inp[i].isalpha():
        print('Enter only numbers')
        break

    if inp[i] == '+' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i:])) + int(''.join(inp[i::])))
        break

    if inp[i] == '*' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i:])) , int(''.join(inp[i::])))
        break

    if inp[i] == '-' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i:])) - int(''.join(inp[i::])))
        break

    if inp[i] == '/' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i:])) / int(''.join(inp[i::])))
        break


    i += 1
```

Comment: А что получается в `print(repr(''.join(inp[i::])))` перед тем как будет ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ```
   if inp[i].isalpha():
       print('Enter only numbers')
       break
   ```

   можно было бы проверить сразу всю введённую строку, а не посимвольно

2. ```
   inp = list(input())
   ```

   можно было бы ввести текст, а по строку двигаться через `for`

   ```
   for letter in inp:
   ```

   или

   ```
   for index in range(len(inp))
   ```

   это тоже удобнее
3. у вас проблемы возникают из-за присутствия пробелов - их можно предварительно удалить из строки, хотя бы

   ```
   inp = list(filter(lambda i: i != ' ', input()))
   ```

   ну или если работать со строкой:

   ```
   inp = input().replace(' ', '')
   ```
4. вместо умножить вы поставили запятую

   ```
    print(int(''.join(inp[:i:])) , int(''.join(inp[i::])))
   ```
5. везде ля второго параметра вы используете `inp[i::]`, куда входит и знак, а надо на 1 символ дальше, т.е. `inp[i+1::]`

Таким образом исправленный код может выглядеть так:

```
inp = list(filter(lambda i: i != ' ', input()))

i = 0

while i != len(inp):

    if inp[i].isalpha():
        print('Enter only numbers')
        break

    if inp[i] == '+' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i])) + int(''.join(inp[i + 1])))
        break

    if inp[i] == '*' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i])) * int(''.join(inp[i + 1])))
        break

    if inp[i] == '-' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i])) - int(''.join(inp[i + 1])))
        break

    if inp[i] == '/' and inp.index(inp[i]) == i and not inp.count(inp[i]) > 1:
        print(int(''.join(inp[:i])) / int(''.join(inp[i + 1])))
        break

    i += 1
```

Но если переписать чуть-чуть, то можно сделать код чуть более понятным:

```
inp = input().replace(' ', '')

for i in range(len(inp)):

    if inp[i].isalpha():
        print('Enter only numbers')
        break

    if 0 < i < len(inp) - 1:
        left = int(inp[:i])
        right = int(inp[i + 1:])

        res = None

        if inp[i] == '+':
            res = left + right

        if inp[i] == '-':
            res = left - right

        if inp[i] == '*':
            res = left * right

        if inp[i] == '/':
            res = left / right

        if res is not None:
            print(res)
            break
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за столь объемлющий ответ, вы мне очень помогли! Хорошего дня вам!